# React call all output .html file into a single parent .html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, application-structure

Do you have any idea how to call each .html with bundle.js to a single parent .html with layout?

```
/Documentation
-- /node_modules
-- index.html
-- bundle.js
-- webpack.config.js
/Marketing
-- /node_modules
-- index.html
-- bundle.js
-- webpack.config.js
-parent.html
```

The main key to achieve here is to isolate the development of each modules (Documentation, Marketing) so that a team can see their work preview.

Stack: React, React-Router, Redux

PS: I use a build tool to run each webpack config for compilation.

Comment: What are you bundling with? If you're using webpack just make separate webpack tasks that both use parent.html and point to each entry point separately... no need to overcomplicate with multiple index's

Comment: @ajmajmajma I am still stuck on this problem until now. Can you give me a 'bare bone' example? its best when we see it.

Comment: just like how you would split your prod and dev tasks, all you have to do is set the `entry` paramter to each different entry point for documentation or marketing, then you have like `webpack:documentation`, and `webpack:marketing` , your webpack.config.js would be in the parent folder and just deviate tasks based on how you have them set up.

Comment: I will test that with React-Router + Redux. Thanks.